# Pattern attribute on input element allows empty values?

Tags: regex, html, validation

I'm requesting the user give me a nickname that is at least 3 characters and at most 30 characters and only contains letters and numbers.

```
<form>
    Nick: <input type="text" name="nick" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,30}">
    <input type="submit" value="Join lobby">
</form>
```

The problem I'm having is that empty forms are accepted.
As expected, strings that have a length of 1, 2, or 31+, or contain punctuation, do not pass.  But if they just don't put anything into the box, it *is* accepted.

How can I fix this?

Comment: +1. I've changed title - if you don't like the edit fill free to rollback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `required` attribute.

```
<input type="text" required name="nick" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,30}" required>
```

Remember that you still need to do validation on the server side.